# What is the difference between 「いろいろ」and 「さまざま」?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, na-adjectives

According to the dictionary, they both mean "various". What is the difference between both words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

いろいろ is used with different items of the same type (like different types of coffee at coffee shop) while さまざま would be for different types of items (tea, coffee, soda,...).

いろいろ is also more casual and used in speech while さまざま is usual written.

Comment: `いろいろ is used with different items of the same type (like different types of coffee at coffee shop) while さまざま would be for different types of items (tea, coffee, soda,...).` そうでしょうか... 「様々な種類のコーヒーを取り揃えて...」「コーヒーには色んな種類が...」も、「様々な商品を取り揃えて...」「色々な商品」「飲み物をいろいろ」「さまざまな飲み物」... どっちも使えると思いますし、ググったらどちらもたくさんヒットしますが。。

Comment: @Chocolate そうですか。じゃ、Chocolateさんにとって、「いろいろ」と「さまざま」は同意語でしょうか。

Comment: @jarmanso7 全く同じでいつでも置き換え可能、というわけではないと思います。「いろいろ」は種類の豊富さに、「さまざま」は違いの多様さに着目したニュアンスがありますし、回答にある通り formality も違いますし、「いろいろ」は副詞にもなりますし・・・

Comment: @Chocolate 説明してくれて、ありがとう！